# UDP broadcast in an iOS app using Adobe Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, broadcast, netbios

I am writing an iOS app that requires NetBIOS name resolution.  It is straightforward to code using the DatagramSocket class in ActionScript.  But unfortunately, for a NetBIOS request, the UDP packet needs to be sent out as a broadcast, and DatagramSocket does not support this.

Is there a solution for this in Flash/ActionScript?  Is the solution an iOS native extension?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in fact a native extension.  [This one](http://blog.aboutme.be/2011/12/10/udp-in-air-for-ios-using-a-native-extension/) is confirmed to be capable of UDP broadcasts.